# Trying to use an ajax get to get a div and its content from another page not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am receiving an error saying: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
I was using jquery load, but I need to pass headers, so I can no longer usethat and need to use jquery

**my links:**

```
<div class="list-group">
     <a class="list-group-item active" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>profile/timeline/<?php echo System::escape($this->user->user_id); ?>"><span><?php echo System::translate("Timelime"); ?></span></a> 
     <a class="list-group-item" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>profile/about/<?php echo System::escape($this->user->user_id); ?>"><span><?php echo System::translate("About"); ?></span></a>
     <a class="list-group-item" href=""><span>Images</span></a>
     <a class="list-group-item" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>profile/friends/<?php echo System::escape($this->user->user_id); ?>"><span><?php echo System::translate("Friends"); ?></span></a>
</div>
```

**my ajax**

```
$(function() {  
    $('.list-group-item').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           url:$(this).attr('href'),
           type:'GET',
           success: function(data){
                $('.layout-content-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('.layout-content-container').html($(data).find('#inner_main_content').html(), function(){
                        $('.layout-content-container').fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                });
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Have I put the function in the correct place?

```
$('.layout-content-container').html($(data).find('#inner_main_content').html(), function(){
     $('.layout-content-container').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Rendered HTML from the other page

```
<div class="col-md-12 layout-content-container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Overview</strong></div>
        <div class="panel-body"> blah blah blah </div>
```

Comment: What is the actual rendered HTML output after the PHP code executes?

Comment: <div class="col-md-12 layout-content-container">
           <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
             <strong>Overview</strong>
         </div>

         <div class="panel-body">
                blah blah blah
         </div>

Comment: Please update the question with that information.

Comment: And, there are no links in that markup. Where is the rendered output of the links within `list-group` that you originally posted in the question?

Comment: I think @DrewGaynor wants the rendered version of **my links:** code

Comment: The links work fine, I dragged and dropped the link in to the navbar which takes me to the page directly whichs shows the content with no errors, so it's something inside the html function in the javascript I'm not too sure what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside clicks anonymous function preserve $(this).attr('href') to some var and do because inside ajax this will point to other object.

```
$(function() {  
$('.list-group-item').click(function(e){
   var ur = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       url:ur,
       type:'GET',
       success: function(data){
            $('.layout-content-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('.layout-content-  container').html($(data).find('#inner_main_content').html(), function(){
                    $('.layout-content-container').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
       }
    });
});
```

});